# Linking external library in QT Creator - Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to link an external library with QT Creator (always works fine with VS, but QT Creator makes this a pain). I get loads of LNK2019 and LNK2001 (Unresolved external symbol).

Here is a screenshot of the errors:
[Errors](http://oi60.tinypic.com/9i4ug2.jpg)

This is how I've done:

QT project file:

```cpp
QT       += core gui network widgets
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = chat
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        client.cpp \
    socket.cpp \
    util.cpp \
    settings.cpp \
    connectionerrorprompt.cpp \
    rsa.cpp \
    secureerrorprompt.cpp \
    aes.cpp

HEADERS  += client.h \
    socket.h \
    includes.h \
    util.h \
    settings.h \
    connectionerrorprompt.h \
    rsa.h \
    secureerrorprompt.h \
    aes.h

FORMS    += client.ui \
    settings.ui \
    connectionerrorprompt.ui \
    secureerrorprompt.ui


LIBS *= -LF:/C++/chilkatlib/chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc12/libs -lChilkatDbgDll_x64 -lChilkatDbg_x64 -lChilkatRelDll_x64 -lChilkatRel_x64

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../C++/chilkatlib/chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc12/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../C++/chilkatlib/chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc12/include
```

aes.h (class that uses the library)

```cpp
#ifndef AES_H
#define AES_H
#include <CkCrypt2.h>
#include <string>

class AES
{
public:
  AES();
  ~AES();
  void setUpAES();
  void encrypt(const char* str);
  void decrypt(char* crypto);
  std::string _crypto;
  const char* _message;

private:
  CkCrypt2 _crypt;
  bool _success;
  const char* _AESkey;
  bool _isKeySet;
};

#endif // AES_H
```

Every error is from aes.cpp when calling any function from the CkCrypt2 class.

Anyone?

Comment: *What* errors? Calling *what* functions? When posting question about build errors, always please include the actual errors (unmodified and complete) in the question.

Comment: That's not QtCreator's problem. QtCreator uses different external compiler, such as msvc, mingw, If you are using msvc, just make sure the correct .lib are linked. And it should work just like VS.

Comment: Yeah I know, I've downloaded the msvc specific version of the library, so the libs should be fine..

Comment: Gonna post the errors and stuff later today!